# React-Router and webpack-dev-server reloading

Tags: webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server

I had been using react-router v4 and noticed that on a reload (e.g. `localhost:8080/route1` I'd get `Cannot Get route1`.  I looked into this and found that one solution is to serve your index.html for all routes (plus static files for the bundle.js request) and react-router routes now behave as desired.

But now that I'm using my own server, I don't get the benefits of webpack-dev-server, e.g. reload on save, caching of bundle for fast re-compile, etc..

So my question is what should I do?  Is there a way to allow webpack-dev-server to deal with the react-router routes issue?  Or should I continue on with my own server and fine some way to emulate the benefits i get from webpack-dev-server?  Or some other thing i have not considered.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue I have fixed by setting the output publicPath in webpack.config.js. This is the folder structure:

```
project-folder
 -webpack.config.js
 -node_modules
 -src
 --index.html
 --js
 ---app
 ----index.bundle.js
 ----index.js
```

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: './src/js/app/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/app'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/src/js/app/',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            js: 'babel-loader',
            scss: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]',
          publicPath: 'js/app/',
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    noInfo: true
  },
};
```

Comment: this is my config now and somehow it works without specifying public path
https://gist.github.com/alexbollbach/7a7abed3b345dd2e819f459a6a495f89

Comment: In my case, to the rooter the root was project-folder, not src as I wanted, so the rooter failed and i needed to change the public path. Anyway, you have fixed the problem without the public path, right? What is the solution adopted?